# How do I fix the SQL syntax in my MS Query?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-query

I have two tables I would like to compare using a Microsoft query in Excel. I'm familiar with SQL Server so I used the syntax that works on that program and am getting and error

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

Am I using the incorrect SQL syntax in my query?

```
SELECT 
    A.Anode, A.LOB, A.Month, A.Year,
    A.Balance - B.Balance as “Balance”,
    A.Yield - B.Yield as “Yield”,
    A.`Cost of Funds (%)` - B.`Cost of Funds (%)` as “Cost of Funds (%)”,
    A.Spread - B.Spread as “Spread”,
    A.`Income/(Expense)` - B.`Income/(Expense)` as “Income/(Expense)”,
    A.`Total Cost of Funds $` - B.`Total Cost of Funds $` as “Total Cost of Funds $”,
    A.Input_Cof - B.Input_Cof as “Input_Cof”,
    A.Input_Yield - B.Input_Yield as “Input_Yield”
FROM 
    `'Cartesian Product - Fcst$'` `'Cartesian Product - Fcst$'` A
LEFT JOIN 
    `'Cartesian Product - Prior$'` `'Cartesian Product - Prior$'` B ON A.Anode = B. Anode, A.LOB = B.LOB, A.Month = B.Month, A.Year = B.Year
```

Comment: Commas in the ON clause? I'd expect AND instead. (or OR, but that would be a bit odd in this case.)

Comment: or is it the space between `B.` and `Anode`?

Comment: And it is probably from copy paste, but those aren't really double quotes. They are special UTF8 characters for displaying left and right double quotes. They are suspect